# Consistency of return type

Tags: java, design-patterns

We have a `Gateway` class that is injected with a persistence medium on initialization.
The business classes will invoke the gateway to persist or request data.

```
Class Gateway {
  Repository rep;(injected on initialization)

  public PersistTypeEnum persistEmployee(Employee){ ... rep.persist......}
  public PersistTypeEnum persistEmployer(Employer){ ... rep.persist......}
  public PersistTypeEnum persistEmployeeForEmployer(EployerEmployee){ ... rep.persist......}



  getEmployee(){ ....rep.getmployee....}
  ...................................... 
}
```

We need to enforce that every persist call via `Gateway` returns `PersistTypeEnum`.
Any recommended practice/pattern for enforcing or achieving this?

Comment: Why not just proper interface?

Comment: Maybe i am not clear on the question - even an interface does not enforce that every new method added returns the PersistTypeEnum

Comment: If you worry about prototype of not existing method yet, only one solution: educate the developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [Strategy Pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). For example instead of adding new `persistEmployee` methods extract this logic outside `Gateway` class to some *processor* classes with common interface like

```
public interface Persistor<T extends Persistable> { // Persistable would be common interface for Employee, Employer, ...
    PersistTypeEnum persist(T Item, Class<T> itemClass);
}
```

and inside your Gateway store such `Persistors` inside a map grouped by `Class`. Then write dispatcher method to call such implementations

```
Map<Class<? extends Persistable>, Persistor> persistors = initializePersistors(); // even better some dependency injection here

...

public <T extends Persistable> PersistTypeEnum persist(T Item, Class<T> itemClass) {
    return persistors.get(itemClass).persist(item); // handle 'no such key' exception 
}
```

This is of course suggestion and there are probably better ways how to implement this, but this approach, I believe, will resolve your issue